# Polymorphic keys - definitive list?

Tags: polymorphism, polymorphic

I am working with salesforce data within SQL, and am trying to come up with a proper solution to handle polymorphism/polymorphic keys. I am aware of the easy ones (whatid/whoid in task and event), however I am wanting to find every example of polymorphism within Salesforce.  Is there a definitive list that is available?

The second part of this question, is determining the proper way to 'lookup' these IDs. Making ~30 joins would kill the performance of my queries, so I am trying to establish a route forward to lookup these values.

Comment: summer 19 includes GA for polymorphic soql: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_api_soql.htm#rn_api_soql

Comment: Hi @cropredy - I have seen that.  However, I am actually working with this data on prem, aka outside of SOQL.  I will give that a try though, and see if I can figure out how to leverage SOQL in that process.  Thanks for the suggestion!!

Comment: Searching the [object reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_concepts.htm) for "ParentId" will find many of them, though with some false positives (eg Case & Account) and probably missing some others. But a good start in the absence of a definitive list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can run an anonymous script like the below to find out for a specific org all of the fields which are polymorphic lookups:

```
for (SObjectType sObjectType : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values())
{
    for (SObjectField field : sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values())
    {
        if (field.getDescribe().getReferenceTo().size() > 1)
        {
            system.debug(sObjectType + '.' + field);
        }
    }
}
```

In a fresh Trailhead Playground, for example, the standard objects returned are:

- AcceptedEventRelation.RelationId
- AccountShare.UserOrGroupId
- ActivityHistory.OwnerId
- ActivityHistory.WhatId
- ActivityHistory.WhoId
- AssetShare.UserOrGroupId
- AttachedContentDocument.LinkedEntityId
- Attachment.OwnerId
- Attachment.ParentId
- AuthConfigProviders.AuthProviderId
- CampaignMember.LeadOrContactId
- CampaignMember.LeadOrContactOwnerId
- CampaignShare.UserOrGroupId
- Case.OwnerId
- CaseShare.UserOrGroupId
- CaseTeamMember.MemberId
- CaseTeamTemplateMember.MemberId
- CollaborationGroupRecord.RecordId
- CollaborationInvitation.SharedEntityId
- CombinedAttachment.ParentId
- ConsumptionSchedule.OwnerId
- ConsumptionScheduleShare.UserOrGroupId
- ContactRequest.OwnerId
- ContactRequest.WhatId
- ContactRequest.WhoId
- ContactRequestShare.UserOrGroupId
- ContactShare.UserOrGroupId
- ContentDistribution.RelatedRecordId
- ContentDocumentLink.LinkedEntityId
- ContentNotification.EntityIdentifierId
- ContentVersion.FirstPublishLocationId
- ContentWorkspaceMember.MemberId
- CustomBrand.ParentId
- CustomBrandAsset.AssetSourceId
- CustomHttpHeader.ParentId
- Dashboard.FolderId
- DeclinedEventRelation.RelationId
- Document.FolderId
- DuplicateRecordItem.RecordId
- EmailMessage.RelatedToId
- EmailMessageRelation.RelationId
- EmailStatus.WhoId
- EmailTemplate.FolderId
- EntityDefinition.DataStewardId
- EntitySubscription.ParentId
- Event.OwnerId
- Event.WhatId
- Event.WhoId
- EventChangeEvent.WhatId
- EventChangeEvent.WhoId
- EventRelation.RelationId
- EventRelationChangeEvent.RelationId
- ExternalDataUserAuth.ExternalDataSourceId
- FeedAttachment.FeedEntityId
- FeedAttachment.RecordId
- FeedComment.FeedItemId
- FeedComment.ParentId
- FeedItem.ParentId
- FeedLike.FeedEntityId
- FeedLike.FeedItemId
- FeedPollChoice.FeedItemId
- FeedPollVote.FeedItemId
- FeedRevision.FeedEntityId
- FeedSignal.FeedEntityId
- FeedSignal.FeedItemId
- FeedTrackedChange.FeedItemId
- FieldDefinition.BusinessOwnerId
- FlowInterview.OwnerId
- FlowInterviewShare.UserOrGroupId
- FlowRecordRelation.RelatedRecordId
- ForecastShare.UserOrGroupId
- Group.OwnerId
- Group.RelatedId
- GroupMember.UserOrGroupId
- Image.OwnerId
- ImageShare.UserOrGroupId
- Lead.OwnerId
- LeadShare.UserOrGroupId
- ListEmail.OwnerId
- ListEmailIndividualRecipient.RecipientId
- ListEmailRecipientSource.SourceListId
- ListEmailShare.UserOrGroupId
- LoginHistory.AuthenticationServiceId
- LookedUpFromActivity.OwnerId
- LookedUpFromActivity.WhatId
- LookedUpFromActivity.WhoId
- Macro.OwnerId
- MacroShare.UserOrGroupId
- Note.ParentId
- NoteAndAttachment.ParentId
- OpenActivity.OwnerId
- OpenActivity.WhatId
- OpenActivity.WhoId
- OpportunityShare.UserOrGroupId
- Order.OwnerId
- OrderShare.UserOrGroupId
- OrgDeleteRequest.OwnerId
- OrgDeleteRequestShare.UserOrGroupId
- OutgoingEmail.RelatedToId
- OutgoingEmail.WhoId
- OutgoingEmailRelation.RelationId
- PermissionSet.LicenseId
- ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId
- ProcessInstanceHistory.ActorId
- ProcessInstanceHistory.OriginalActorId
- ProcessInstanceHistory.TargetObjectId
- ProcessInstanceStep.ActorId
- ProcessInstanceStep.OriginalActorId
- ProcessInstanceWorkitem.ActorId
- ProcessInstanceWorkitem.OriginalActorId
- QuickText.OwnerId
- QuickTextShare.UserOrGroupId
- RecordAction.RecordId
- RecordActionHistory.ParentRecordId
- Report.OwnerId
- SetupEntityAccess.SetupEntityId
- StreamingChannel.OwnerId
- StreamingChannelShare.UserOrGroupId
- Task.WhatId
- Task.WhoId
- TaskChangeEvent.WhatId
- TaskChangeEvent.WhoId
- TodayGoal.OwnerId
- TodayGoalShare.UserOrGroupId
- TopicAssignment.EntityId
- UndecidedEventRelation.RelationId
- User.DelegatedApproverId
- UserAppMenuCustomization.OwnerId
- UserAppMenuCustomizationShare.UserOrGroupId
- UserChangeEvent.DelegatedApproverId
- UserEmailPreferredPerson.OwnerId
- UserEmailPreferredPerson.PersonRecordId
- UserEmailPreferredPersonShare.UserOrGroupId
- UserProvisioningRequest.OwnerId
- UserProvisioningRequestShare.UserOrGroupId
- UserShare.UserOrGroupId
- Vote.ParentId
- WebLink.ScontrolId