# Why is CaseFeed.CreatedById Polymorphic?

Tags: soql, compile-error, casefeed, polymorphism

A polymorphic lookup is, by definition, one where the `SObjectType` of the parent be multiple different values. That was the basis for how I compiled [Polymorphic keys - definitive list?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/264614/2995)

However, a colleague stumbled across another "polymorphic" relationship via other means, namely a SOQL compile fail. Here's the query:

```
SELECT CreatedBy.UserType FROM CaseFeed WHERE ...
```

And the error:

> No such column 'UserType' on entity 'Name'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

That error seems to clearly indicate this lookup is polymorphic.

Looking at the above data points, I was pretty shocked. `CreatedBy` is *always* a `User`, everywhere in the system. Just to sanity check, I ran the below script:

```
system.debug(CaseFeed.CreatedById.getDescribe().getReferenceTo());
```

The log output was as expected:

> USER_DEBUG [1]|DEBUG|(User)

One line of investigation clearly indicates this field is *not* polymorphic. The other seems to indicate it is polymorphic. I'm strongly inclined to believe the former. Is there a platform bug or Known Issue here? Or is it expected behavior?

Comment: Probably a bug, the documentation for the CaseFeed (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_associated_objects_feed.htm) does not make any remarks about the CreatedBy field (there's a slightly caveat for two types of feed, but seem unrelated

Comment: This issue also affects `FeedItem`, `FeedComment`, and `CaseHistory`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson although not explicitly mentioned why but you might want to read [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_filtering_polymorphic_relationships.htm) and check SOQL `SELECT CreatedBy.Type from CaseFeed` results, which seems to confirm that `CreatedById` is polymorphic in these special cases because it shows up the [Name](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_name.htm) object

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like before Spring 12, `CreatedBy` field, on some objects, could be linked with `User` or `SelfServiceUser` object.

Refer to screenshot below obtained from a 2010 blog post (link to blog is no longer active) :

[image]

`SelfServiceUser` is no longer available in new orgs as per doc [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_selfserviceuser.htm) but since still active in older orgs, it remains polymorphic :

> SelfServiceUser
> Represents a Contact who has been enabled to use your organization’s Self-Service portal, where he or she can obtain online support.
> Starting with Spring 12, the Self-Service portal isn’t available for new orgs. Existing orgs continue to have access to the Self-Service portal.

[image]